# Equations in different part of the text not aligned

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, matrices

I have a problem, in my document I have two sets of similar equations but they do not align.

This is the text:

```
If $\tilde{\mathbf{p}}$ is first combined with the system of Eq.\ref{inplane:eq7} and then differentiated with respect to time, it yields 
\begin{equation}
\label{4:eq18}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot{p}_{1} \\
\dot{p}_{2} \\
\dot{p}_{3} \\
\dot{p}_{4}
\end{array}\right]
= \omega 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 4\sigma-3 & -2(\sigma-1) & 0  \\
2\sigma - 3 & 0 & 0 & 4(\sigma-1) \\
4(\sigma-1) & 0 & 0 & 8\sigma-5 \\
0 & -2(\sigma - 1) & \sigma-1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
p_{1} \\
p_{2} \\
p_{3} \\
p_{4}
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
From this system of equations, it is then possible to differentiate even further to a second order system as
\begin{equation}
\label{4:eq19}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\ddot{p}_{1} \\
\ddot{p}_{2} \\
\ddot{p}_{3} \\
\ddot{p}_{4}
\end{array}\right]
= \omega^{2} 
\begin{bmatrix}
-(2\sigma -1) & 0& 0 & -2(\sigma -1) \\
0 & -(2\sigma -1) & 2(\sigma-1) & 0 \\
0 & -2(\sigma -1) & 3(\sigma-1) & 0 \\
2(\sigma -1) & 0 &0& 3(\sigma-1)
\end{bmatrix}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
p_{1} \\
p_{2} \\
p_{3} \\
p_{4}
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
In Eq. \ref{4:eq19}, the variables are coupled again ($p_{1}$ with $p_{4}$ and $p_{2}$ with $p_{3}$).
```

I am working in a book environment and I do not have any other problems of this kind in my thesis. In the image you can see what's actually going on. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

[image: Equations misalignment.]

Comment: Welcome to SE! How you like to have aligned? The equation is not equal (have different width), so they align in text had to be different.

Comment: Thanks for your welcoming message! :)
I know they have different width but the equations should be both centred, and they do not look centred to me; the second one looks like it is pushed on the left...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much ore likely that they will!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I compile the OP's snippet, I do not get the left/right offset that is shown in his image.  The OP will need to provide a complete working example to demonstrate the problem.

When I wrap the OP's provided code in a document with `amsmath`, I get this image:

[image]

which is centered, but of uneven width.  One thing that can be done is to redefine the length `\arraycolsep` in the second equation to 3.9pt.  When that is done, the two equations end up a similar width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

If $\tilde{\mathbf{p}}$ is first combined with the system of Eq.\ref{inplane:eq7} and then differentiated with respect to time, it yields 
\begin{equation}
\label{4:eq18}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot{p}_{1} \\
\dot{p}_{2} \\
\dot{p}_{3} \\
\dot{p}_{4}
\end{array}\right]
= \omega 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 4\sigma-3 & -2(\sigma-1) & 0  \\
2\sigma - 3 & 0 & 0 & 4(\sigma-1) \\
4(\sigma-1) & 0 & 0 & 8\sigma-5 \\
0 & -2(\sigma - 1) & \sigma-1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
p_{1} \\
p_{2} \\
p_{3} \\
p_{4}
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
From this system of equations, it is then possible to differentiate even further to a second order system as
\begin{equation}
\label{4:eq19}
\arraycolsep3.9pt
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\ddot{p}_{1} \\
\ddot{p}_{2} \\
\ddot{p}_{3} \\
\ddot{p}_{4}
\end{array}\right]
= \omega^{2} 
\begin{bmatrix}
-(2\sigma -1) & 0& 0 & -2(\sigma -1) \\
0 & -(2\sigma -1) & 2(\sigma-1) & 0 \\
0 & -2(\sigma -1) & 3(\sigma-1) & 0 \\
2(\sigma -1) & 0 &0& 3(\sigma-1)
\end{bmatrix}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
p_{1} \\
p_{2} \\
p_{3} \\
p_{4}
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
In Eq. \ref{4:eq19}, the variables are coupled again ($p_{1}$ with $p_{4}$ and $p_{2}$ with $p_{3}$). 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have already amsmath set in the header of my file, but I am not sure why I obtain a different result, compared to your first one. 
In any case your answer looks brilliant to me, thanks for your help!